# Clarifications how to use Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

Anyone with a bit of experience would be kind to clarify the GA/GA-old/GTM mix for me?

I am using GTM (Google Tag Manager) and I basically inject this in the DOM on page load (I got this script from GTM):

```
const scriptTag = `
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js',${JSON.stringify(events).slice(1, -1)}});
      var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
      j.async=true;j.src='${protocol}://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl+'${gtm_auth}${gtm_preview}&gtm_cookies_win=x';
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','${dataLayerName}','${id}');`;
```

I have set up a "Universal Google Analytics" on my GTM, and I have `ga` function available in the browser console. I have successfully used the `dataLayer` feature of GTM and I can see my dataLayer get filled when using the preview GTM mode.

But, I don't understand how to link the variables I store in the dataLayer to GA, I save a `env` variable in my `dataLayer`, and I have added a "data layer" variable `env` on GTM, but I feel like I missed a step to link that variable to GA. (None of the variables I save in my dataLayer are stored into GA)

I also heard about the "new GA way", which relies on `gtag`... But I don't have a `gtag` function created by the "google analytics" script injected by GTM.

I'm getting lost in what is supposed to be the way of doing things.

Old way: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

New way: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications

*(I'm building a SPA)*

So:

1. How to link GTM dataLayer and events data to GA?
2. Should I use gtag instead of ga? I don't understand why GTM doesn't include the new version of GA with `gtag`

Comment: Are you having issues getting the dataLayer value to the tag or are you having trouble triggering a tag to fire when a value is added to the dataLayer?

Comment: @BrianNorman There are several issues. 1) my GTM dataLayer gets filled correctly, but those values aren't accessible in GA console. 2) I don't know if I should load `www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js` or `www.googletagmanager.com/gtag.js` script to fire my events.

Comment: When you say 'GA console', are you referring to the browser's js console?  I am using gtm.js on my site.  Do you have any variables set up in GTM to store the dataLayer values which can then be used in your Universal Analytics tags?

Comment: by `GA console` I mean the GA Dashboard at https://analytics.google.com/ and yes, I created variables in GTM dashboard for my dataLayer variables, and when using the preview mode, they show up on the browser GTM debug view and they're correctly set, but not sent back to analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Google Analytics Settings variable set up that your are setting on your Universal Analytics tags?

My settings variable looks like this:

[image: GA Settings Variable]

The tracking ID variable set in the image above looks like this:

[image: Tracking ID Variable]

Then, in my Universal Analytics event tag, I set the settings variable in the tag configuration:
[image]

Comment: Most of my issues were related to tags not firing, I had triggers, but no tags to fire them. I eventually used GTM + gtag.js for my events and I used `ga()` for manual pageviews (SPA)